# Magnetic susceptibility of electron gas in non-uniform magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electrons, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

Someone can explain briefly how to treat with perturbation theory a free electron gas in a sinusoidal external magnetic field ? I'm trying to understand the paramagnetic response of an electron gas to a non uniform magnetic field

Answer (score 0):

A free electron gas exhibits Landau *diamagnetism*. It is not paramagnetic.